# Can you stream and batch from the same delta table?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks

I tried to stream and batch from the same delta table but ran into small files problem on the batch side. But if you optimize the delta table, the streaming size will lose track of the files it reads because the compaction results of the optimization.

Comment: Databricks uses `AtomicCommitProtocol`. Running optimization should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When the `OPTIMIZE` command removes small files and adds back in compacted ones, these operations are flagged with the [`dataChange`](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/d29a0e1a797be2b6911fc26cea92649b4ed11424/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/delta/actions/actions.scala#L98) flag set to false. This flag tells streams that are following the transaction log that it is safe to ignore this transaction to avoid processing duplicate data.

I'll also note that [DBR 5.3](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/5.3.html#private-preview-features) contains a private preview features called Auto-Optimize, that can perform this compaction before small files even make it into the table. This feature will be GA-ed in the next release of DBR.